# How i can make curl request in Android app?

Tags: java, android, http, curl

I'm trying to make an application to work with the SMS distribution
service API. To send a message, I need to complete a curl request

```
https://email:api_key@gate.smsaero.ru/v2/sms/send?numbers[]=79990000000&numbers[]=79990000001&text=your+text&sign=SMS Aero&channel=DIRECT
```

How can this be implemented in Android?

Comment: Use okhttp2 for http requests

Comment: @Remario basic http request will work?

Answer (score 0):

This may works

```java
public void send(String url) throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            }
        });
    }
```